# Looking for a word similar to 'supervise' but for inanimate objects

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

The sentence in question is "The solar panels in this region are supervised by XXX." The word 'supervision' obviously doesn't fit, but I can't think of any suitable alternatives.

'Operate' seems strange since there is only monitoring and maintenance involved, no active operation.

'Manage' is a bit too vague.

Is there a good word for situations like this? Or is there another short and concise way to express what is said in the sentence?

Comment: Why not "administered"? Or maybe "controlled"?

Comment: I think you should reconsider "supervised". What about your own words: "monitored" or "maintained"? Or both of them together. Or "overseen"?

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty "Monitored" or "maintained" would be a bit too specific. Both together would be too lengthy.

Comment: @SovereignSun I will consider "administered," thank you.